# geth sendTransaction not working

Tags: ethereum, geth

I have a geth server that I need to transfer some ethereum to other wallet. I studdied the wiki page of geth and found out there is a method called sendTransaction for this job.

**First:** I used the following command to transfer money, the resault gave me a transaction hash but it didn't transfer money to the desired wallet.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:"WALLET-Address", value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether")});
response: 0x....
```

**Second:** I used combination of some gas and gasPrice parameters to do the transaction but the result was the same. like this one:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:"WALLET-Address", value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether"), gas: 100000, gasPrice: web3.toWei(14000,'gwei')})
response: 0x...
```

**Important** i have to mention, the transaction didn't show up in etherscan.io.

please help me to figure out this problem. Thanks.

**EDITED**
It is not my own private network. this is a project and i am coding for someone else

I this is my JS code to, Please tell me what is the problem

```
#!/usr/bin/nodejs

var loadedWeb3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new loadedWeb3();

const URL = 'http://<IP>:8545';

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(URL));

var req = {
    to:"My-Wallet",
    from: "SourceWallet",
    value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'),
    gasLimit : 21000,
    gasPrice : 20000000000
};

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(req.from).then(console.log);

web3.eth.sendTransaction(req)
    .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
        console.log("TxHash: " + hash);
        web3.eth.getTransaction(hash).then(console.log);
    })
    .on('receipt', function(receipt){
        console.log("Receipt: " + receipt);
        console.log(receipt);
    })
    .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
        console.log("confirmed -> " + confirmationNumber);
        console.log(confirmationNumber);
        console.log("Receipt -> " + receipt);
        console.log(receipt);
    })
    .on('error', console.error);
```

Comment: Is it your own private Ethereum network?

Comment: It is not my own private network. this is a project and i am coding for someone else

Answer (score 1):

First: You need funds. To send ether you need ether. To send 0.05 ether you probably gonna spend 0.06 (0.05 + 0.01 transaction costs).

Second: You need to have the wallet unlocked at your node.

Third: check if eth.coinbase has funds as it is the wallet you are trying to get ether from. I would advise you to check if eth.accounts[0] has funds too.

At the end, I would advise you to try things on a private network before using the real network. It's a lot easier and cheaper.

Comment: Thanks dude, all the conditions are ok

Comment: Now I get 24 confirms but still i dont money in my wallet

Answer (score 0):

## Additional information

I used following code in NodeJS for money transfer I got Transaction Hash + 25 Confirmations but no money transferred.

```js
#!/usr/bin/nodejs

var loadedWeb3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new loadedWeb3();

const URL = 'http://<IP>:8545';

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(URL));

var req = {
    to:"Destination Wallet",
    from: "Source Wallet",
    value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')
};

web3.eth.sendTransaction(req)
    .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
        web3.eth.getTransaction(hash).then(function(trans) {
            var line = "====================================";
            console.log(line + " Transaction " + line);
            console.log("      From: " + trans.from);
            console.log("        To: " + trans.to);
            console.log("Trans Hash: " + trans.hash);
            console.log("  Ethereum: " + web3.utils.fromWei(trans.value.toString(), 'ether'));
            console.log(" Gas Limit: " + trans.gas);
            console.log(" Gas Price: " + web3.utils.fromWei(trans.gasPrice.toString(), 'Gwei'));
        });
    })
    .on('receipt', function(receipt){
        var line = "======================================";
        console.log(line + " Receipt " + line);
        console.log("Block Hash: " + receipt.blockHash);
        console.log("Block Code: " + receipt.blockNumber);
        console.log("  Used Gas: " + receipt.gasUsed);
        console.log(line + "=========" + line);
    })
    .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
        console.log("Confirm Code: " + confirmationNumber);
    })
    .on('error', console.error);
```

and the Following response appeared:

```js
==================================== Transaction ====================================
      From: 0x1234400000000000000000000000000000000000
        To: 0x1234500000000000000000000000000000000000
Trans Hash: 0xeaffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
 Gas Limit: 90000
 Gas Price: 0.00009
Confirm Code: 0
====================================== Receipt ======================================
Block Hash: 0x8bcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
Block Code: 41962
  Used Gas: 21000
=====================================================================================
Confirm Code: 1
Confirm Code: 2
Confirm Code: 3
Confirm Code: 4
Confirm Code: 5
Confirm Code: 6
Confirm Code: 7
Confirm Code: 8
Confirm Code: 9
Confirm Code: 10
Confirm Code: 11
Confirm Code: 12
Confirm Code: 13
Confirm Code: 14
Confirm Code: 15
Confirm Code: 16
Confirm Code: 17
Confirm Code: 18
Confirm Code: 19
Confirm Code: 20
Confirm Code: 21
Confirm Code: 22
Confirm Code: 23
Confirm Code: 24
```

but the transaction is not in https://etherscan.io and money didn't transfer.